# Symfony - Ajaxify table filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

In my journey to learn Symfony (version 3) I've built a Customer list with a filter form. I have searched the internet on some examples to *ajaxify* the table results based on the provide filters. Most information are on existing bundles like [stwe/DatatablesBundle](https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle) or use Symfony in combination with [Angular](https://florian.voutzinos.com/blog/data-tables-with-symfony-angular/)/ReactJS.

The last option mentioned is in fact very interesting but as an beginning Symfony developer I'm more interested in building this functionality from scratch in Symfony/Javascript or JQuery. 
In other words instructions similar to the http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp but Symfony specific.

I'm familiar with creating a JSON response but what is the best way to bind the data? Writing it out in JQuery? ...

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion would be to have a template that renders only your data rows. Then create a Controller action whose purpose is to fetch data using your filters and render this data using the `data_rows` template.

```
public function tableAction(Request $request)
{
    $filters = // ...
    $rows = $repository->findAllWithFilters($filters);

    // ...

    return $this->render('data_rows.html.twig', ['rows' => $rows]);
}
```

Finally, use `render controller` in your "main" action to include this request as a sub-request for your main view:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:table', {'filters': filters})) }}
```

When that's done, you can directly call the `tableAction` route in your jQuery script, which will return the rendered rows. Just append the rows in your HTML and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion I will give this a try